# Efficient way of performing geometrical operations

Tags: tikz-pgf, polygon, anchor

I have to draw a series of regular (equiangular, actually) polygons, each of which is constructed by trisecting the sides of the previous polygon and subsequently cutting off its corners.

Right now I'm putting in all the coordinates manually for each polygon:

```
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (E) at (0.1,0);
    \coordinate (F) at (2.1,0);
    \coordinate (G) at ($(F)+(120:2cm)$);

    \coordinate (eg1) at ($(E)+(0:0.666cm)$);
    \coordinate (eg2) at ($(E)+(0:1.333cm)$);
    \coordinate (gf1) at ($(F)+(120:0.666cm)$);
    \coordinate (gf2) at ($(F)+(120:1.333cm)$);
    \coordinate (ef1) at ($(E)+(60:0.666cm)$);
    \coordinate (ef2) at ($(E)+(60:1.333cm)$);

    \draw (-2.1,0) -- (-0.1,0) -- ++(120:2cm) -- cycle;
    \draw (-2.1,0)++(60:0.666cm) -- +(150:1pt) -- +(150:-1pt);
    \draw (-2.1,0)++(60:1.333cm) -- +(150:1pt) -- +(150:-1pt);
    \draw (-2.1,0)++(0:0.666cm) -- +(90:1pt) -- +(90:-1pt);
    \draw (-2.1,0)++(0:1.333cm) -- +(90:1pt) -- +(90:-1pt);
    \draw (-0.1,0)++(120:0.666cm) -- +(210:1pt) -- +(210:-1pt);
    \draw (-0.1,0)++(120:1.333cm) -- +(210:1pt) -- +(210:-1pt);
\end{tikzpicture} %
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (E) at (0.1,0);
    \coordinate (F) at (2.1,0);
    \coordinate (G) at ($(F)+(120:2cm)$);

    \coordinate (eg1) at ($(E)+(0:0.666cm)$);
    \coordinate (eg2) at ($(E)+(0:1.333cm)$);
    \coordinate (gf1) at ($(F)+(120:0.666cm)$);
    \coordinate (gf2) at ($(F)+(120:1.333cm)$);
    \coordinate (ef1) at ($(E)+(60:0.666cm)$);
    \coordinate (ef2) at ($(E)+(60:1.333cm)$);

    \coordinate (p) at ($(ef1)+(120:-0.222cm)$);
    \coordinate (q) at ($(ef1)+(60:0.222cm)$);
    \coordinate (r) at ($(ef1)+(120:-0.444cm)$);
    \coordinate (s) at ($(ef1)+(60:0.444cm)$);


    \draw (eg1)--(eg2)--(gf1)--(gf2)--(ef2) --(ef1)--cycle;

    \draw (p)--+(210:1pt)--+(210:-1pt);
    \draw (q)--+(150:1pt)--+(150:-1pt);
    \draw (r)--+(210:1pt)--+(210:-1pt);
    \draw (s)--+(150:1pt)--+(150:-1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}&%
&%
&%
& 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw circle (0.566cm);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{tabular}
```

Right now I only have two of these polygons put in because it's so unbelievably tedious:

[image: output screenshot]

Is there a way to "automate" this process? Like using some `\foreach` expression or something similar? I haven't been able to find one so far.

Comment: Something like `\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {3,6,...,15}{
    \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\x,draw,minimum width=3/\xi*1cm,anchor=south] (s-\xi) at (\x/1.5,0) {};
}`? You can then draw the seperators on the edges

Comment: @percusse gives error messages about not recognizing key 'regular polygon'

Comment: You need `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}` to use the node shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure you've described 
provides only two regular polygons,
triangle and hexagon. 
All the following constructed polygons 
will not be equilateral,
that is, there will be sides 
of different lengths.
If this is the intension, here is 
one way to do it using Asymptote:

```
// trisectpoly.asy
// run 
// asy trisectpoly.asy
// to get trisectpoly.pdf

settings.tex="pdflatex";
import graph;
size(9cm);
pen linePen=darkblue+0.7bp;
pair[] f(pair[] p){
  pair[] q;
  for(int i=0;i<p.length;++i){
    q.push((2p[i]+ p[i+1])/3);
    q.push(( p[i]+2p[i+1])/3);
  }
  q.cyclic=true;
  return q;
}

real a=1;
pair[]p={0,(a,0),a/2*(1,sqrt(3))};
p.cyclic=true;
draw(graph(p)--cycle,linePen);
int n=10;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
  p=f(p);
  draw(shift((i+1)*a)*(graph(p)--cycle),linePen);
}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I integrate the Asymptote script in my LaTeX document, though?

Comment: @Anakhand: if you really (really?) need to embedded asy picture,
that is, that there is some reason that `\includegraphics{trisectpoly.pdf}`
is not enough,
you can always use `\begin{asy}` environment 
provided by `\usepackage{asymptote}`,
check the asymptote docs or `[asymptote]` tagged questions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal. The marks are set by markings, and the coordinates are set at positions 1/3 and 2/3 of the edges. You can iterate this as long as you want, I already put the definitions of the next coordinates in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{mymark/.style={postaction={decorate,
   decoration={markings,mark=at position 1/3 with {\draw(0,-2pt)--(0,2pt);},
   mark=at position 2/3 with {\draw(0,-2pt)--(0,2pt);}}
   }}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (E) at (-30:1cm);
    \coordinate (F) at (90:1cm);
    \coordinate (G) at (210:1cm);
    \foreach \X/\Y in {E/F,F/G,G/E}
    {
    \draw[mymark] (\X)--(\Y) coordinate[pos={1/3}] (\X 1\Y) coordinate[pos={2/3}] (\X 2\Y);
    % the coordinates are not needed at this stage
    }
\end{tikzpicture} %
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (E) at (-30:1cm);
    \coordinate (F) at (90:1cm);
    \coordinate (G) at (210:1cm);
    \foreach \X/\Y in {E/F,F/G,G/E}
    {
    \path (\X)--(\Y) coordinate[pos={1/3}] (\X 1\Y) coordinate[pos={2/3}] (\X 2\Y);
    }

    \foreach \X/\Y/\Z in {E/F/G,F/G/E,G/E/F}
    {\draw[mymark] (\X 2\Y)--(\Y 1\Z) 
    coordinate[pos={1/3}] (\X\Y\Z 1) coordinate[pos={2/3}] (\X\Y\Z 2);
    % the coordinates are not needed at this stage
    \draw[mymark] (\X 1\Y)--(\X 2\Y)
    coordinate[pos={1/3}] (\X\Y 1) coordinate[pos={2/3}] (\X\Y 2); }
    % the coordinates are not needed at this stage
    % but define the corners of the next contour
\end{tikzpicture} %
%
&%
&%
& 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw circle (0.566cm);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]